# Non-singular Conics are equivalent to some projective line.

Tags: solution-verification, conic-sections, projective-geometry, bilinear-form

[The proof begins on pg.22.](https://courses-archive.maths.ox.ac.uk/node/view_material/56460)

I am having trouble understanding why ${B|}_{W_y} \not\equiv 0$.

Since I couldn't understand this part of the proof (on pg. 24 of the slides), I was trying to show it differently in my own way.

> Assume ${B|}_{W_y} \equiv 0$.
>
> Then, $B(ax+by,ax+by)=0$ for any $a,b \in \mathbb{F}$.
>
> We can expand the equation above, and the expanded equation is $$2abB(x,y)+b^2 B(y,y)=0$$ since $B(x,x)=0$.
>
> The equation implies that $b=0$ or $2aB(x,y)+bB(y,y)=0$.
>
> However, $b =0$ is a contradiction since there exists vector in $W_y$ s.t $b \neq 0$.
>
> Thus, $2aB(x,y)+bB(y,y)=0$ for any $a,b \in \mathbb{F}$.
>
> And, this implies that $B(x,y)=B(y,y)=0$.
>
> But then, $L$ is the conic by the definition of the conic $C$.
>
> However, $x \notin L$, therefore it is also a contradiction.
>
> Hence,  ${B|}_{W_y} \not\equiv 0$.

This is significantly lengthier than the original proof in the link, but it's easier for me because I'm not good at linear algebra.

Is my answer OK?